# How can I completely repaint the canvas of a Java frame?

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

I am using AWT in Java to create animated frame. It is composed of a `Frame` and a `Canvas`, as well as some other components. The code basically is:

```
public class MyFrame extends Frame implements Runnable{

     private Canvas c = new Canvas();
     public  MyFrame(){

        c.setSize(100, 100);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        this.add(c);
     }

}
```

Now I want to draw a part of an image on the canvas. I tried using the frame's paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

     Graphics canvasG = c.getGraphics();
     canvasG.drawImage(img, x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2, null);

{
```

This draws the part of the picture, over the part that has been drawn previously. I, however, want to repaint the canvas completely.

Comment: You could try blanking out the entire canvas: `g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());` Also, you final bracket is facing the wrong way in paint()

Comment: I'm not clear in what is your question. Two tips would be 1. Use Swing instead of AWT. 2. Use double-buffering for your animation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html)

Comment: @madth3 The question is how to completely repaint a component inside another component. In this case a canvas inside a frame.

Comment: @RyanAmos That might work, however I'm trying to understand component repainting rather than finding a quick solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Still curious why AWT which is over 12 yrs out of date and not Swing, which is about 5 yrs out of date.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Still curious about how would YOU solve this question.

Comment: ***I*** would solve it by creating a Swing application, not an AWT.

Comment: Regarding your statement: `" Well why don't you find a Swing thread then and try to satisfy your ego there."`: Your comment was completely uncalled for and unprovoked. Why the personal attack? Please tell me where in my comments above you see a personal attack from me to you?

Comment: I have not lectured you -- all I did was ask a question, one that was mentioned by madth3 above. Our reasons for asking are string as Swing is much more flexible and powerful than AWT. Appropriate responses from you could be "because my instructor required", "because of xxx hardware limitations" or simply "because that's what I want to do", not an uncalled for personal attack on the person who is simply asking a question. I would be happy to engage you in a dialog on anything here, but insist that you first retract and delete your previous uncalled for statement.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Since neither of your previous comments ended with a question mark I perceived them as statements rather than questions. Had I written "Because I wanted to" I'd undoubtedly be given lecture by you on rudeness. Nevertheless neither of the "appropriate responses" i could have offered, would've made this question clearer. This is a Java AWT related question as stated in the tags. WHY is not the issue here.

Comment: -1.  For stating 1) *"I'd appreciate any opinion."* While actually abusing those who offered one. 2) Not interpreting 'curiosity' as 'here is a good chance to explain'. 3) *"WHY is not the issue here."*  It is if you want answers from the people that can help.

Comment: @AndrewThompson 1. What _I_ don't really understand is, how the "abused" parties, are so eager in explaining how this site works, or for that matter how anything else works except staying on the subject and answering a simple question. 2. Your "curiosity", again, has nothing to do with the question above, thus, your comment is merely an expression of personal attitude rather than being helpful on the subject. 3. If you feel offended (yet I fail to see how, since you engage me) just move to the next thread.

Comment: *"a simple question"*  "What is the meaning of life?" Is a simple question.  It is the answer that is more tricky.  To put that another way.  The complexity of the answer is not directly related to the complexity of the question.  Usually when people on SO ask 'Why?' it is for a good reason, to narrow down the possibilities of the best way to approach the problem.  In short, if you wish to persist with this attitude of "It is my business to know, just answer the damn question!", I can see you getting little help.  But then that is your problem, not mine, nor that of anyone else.  Good luck. :)

Comment: @All Swing is not out of date, don't forget that the best IDEs are using Swing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Suppose the question was: "How do I boil a chicken egg?" (in this case "how do I repaint a AWT Canvas?"). I do not see any relevance in determining the age of the chicken (AWT 12ysr old, or Swing 5yrs old) nor do I see any helpful remark in "I'd use ducks egg instead" ("I'd solve it by making a Swing application.") If you could please point out for me a single question asked I'd be delighted to further elaborate. I also fail to see any subject-related curiosity questions or remarks in your comments. All you've done so far is defend your friend.

Comment: As far as Java goes, you should avoid AWT. Swing has a lot more flexible, plus it's lightweight (all in Java). @andrewthompson is correct, as is hoverfullofeels. Switch to AWT and your life will be easier. AWT vs swing: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26970

Comment: Another issue is purely practical; since Swing has mostly overtaken AWT as the de facto Java GUI library, you will often have trouble finding an AWT guru to answer your questions, while it is quite the opposite with Swing. In fact this thread is a case in point: if this had been a Swing question, the OP would likely have 5 answers right now, rather than 0 answers and 17 comments.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Congratulations on proving your point. Now, will you please consider this: It's approx. 24 hours since this was posted. You are still here and still commenting, trying to prove your point to a group of strangers you've never met as well as to an arrogant insulting person (me) on top of that. Well, this certainly implies nothing on your ego. An egocentric person would surely do the opposite. I was mistaken to think that you only seek to boost your ego and I sincerely apologize. Wow, look at that yet another argument won! Congrats on that as well.

Comment: Be sarcastic if you wish, and you'll definitely encourage folks in the future to help you here, or you could accept some of this advice as actually helpful. I'm guessing you're a glass is half-empty kind of guy

Comment: In the future, please take extended discussions to one of the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I'm not sure that the OP has enough reputation points to use the chat rooms.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels D'oh!  You're right.  Carry on.  :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Well, since this is an open post, I can't stop people from (ab)using it to feel important. I guess the advice is to ignore egocentric jerks. Now that's a good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. To answer your question:

- Don't draw in the class that extends Frame but rather in the paint method of a class that extends Canvas. In other words, create a class called MyCanvas that extends Canvas and give it a paint method override.
- Create an object of this class and add it to the Frame so it can be displayed.
- The first call in your Canvas class's paint method override should be the super method, `super.paint(g)`. This will redraw the Canvas erasing things that need to be erased.
- Don't use getGraphics to get a Graphics object from a component since the object obtained will not persist causing bad side effects (try this and then minimize and restore your GUI to see what I mean).
- Instead use the Graphics object obtained from the JVM and passed into the paint method.
- The exception to this is when working with BufferedImages. For them, yeah, go ahead and get the graphics object via `getGraphics()` when you need, it, but just don't forget to dispose of it when you're done so as not to run out of system resources.

Have fun.

Comment: @timpost: thank you for the edit, and I quite frankly do not recall making that terrible staatement. It was posted at a time when I was somewhat new and had yet to learn proper site etiquette.